# Run GroovyTestCase in embedded Groovy?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy

How can you run GroovyTestCase unit tests inside a Groovy script that is running inside a Java program?

The use here is for running GroovyTestCases inside of SoapUI.

Given:

```
class ExperimentClassTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testExperimentClass() {
        assertEquals( new ExperimentClass(name: "Hi").name, "Hi" )
    }
}
class ExperimentClass {String name}
```

Then (works):

```
C:\groovytest>\groovy2.6.0\bin\groovy .\ExperimentClassTest.groovy
.
Time: 0.041

OK (1 test)
```

But given this (contents of a Groovy script run by SoapUI):

```
evaluate (new File ('C:/groovytest/ExperimentClassTest.groovy'))
```

Then (doesn't work):

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ExperimentClassTest.main()
```

Also tried:

```
new ExperimentClassTest().run()
```

... which does return a junit.framework.TestResult, but the test hasn't actually run...

```
new ExperimentClassTest().run().failures().collect {it}
```

returns

```
"TestCase.fName cannot be null"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
new GroovyShell().run( new File('./ExperimentClassTest.groovy'), [] )
```

actually when you run it as `groovy .\ExperimentClassTest.groovy`

GroovyShell is called and by class it detects how to run it

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.java#L295

finally the GroovyShell uses approximately this code to run test case class:

```
def scriptClass = this.getClass().getClassLoader().parseClass( new File('./ExperimentClassTest.groovy') )
def suite = new junit.framework.TestSuite(scriptClass)
def result = junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed.